# How can I read a string from a URL to Arduino (webserver) simply instead of just a character?

Tags: arduino

Here is example code:

In this code, it detects the dollar sign and then identifies the character, either 1, 2, 3, etc. If this is entered, `http://x.x.x.x/$1` - meaning, it chooses block condition 1.

Etc.

I need to change this code, so that I could read the string and store it in a variable.

Maybe I could have `http://x.x.x.x/$25` or $45 or $100, etc.

```
void connection()
{
    EthernetClient client=server.available();

    if (client)
    {
        boolean currentLineIsBlank=true;

        while (client.connected()) {
            if (client.available()) {
                char c = client.read();

                if (incoming && c==' ')
                {
                    incoming=0;
                }
                if (c=='$')
                {
                    incoming=1;
                }
                //Checks for the URL string $1 or $2 and so on.
                if (incoming==1)
                {
                    if(c=='1')
                    {
                        //Insert something
                    }
                    if(c=='2')
                    {

                    }
                    if(c=='3')
                    {
                        redAll();
                    }
                }
                if(c=='\n')
                {
                    currentLineIsBlank=true;
                }
                else if(c!='\r')
                {
                    currentLineIsBlank=false;
                }
            }
        }
        delay(1);
        client.stop();
    }
}
```

What should I do? For the Arduino to read a string. What should I change with this code?

Answer (score 1):

Adafruit's [SDWebBrowse](https://github.com/adafruit/SDWebBrowse) example is most typical of what I find. In that, it builds the character's into a character string for processing later.

```
  ...
  if (client.available()) {
      char c = client.read();

      // If it isn't a new line, add the character to the buffer
      if (c != '\n' && c != '\r') {
          clientline[index] = c;
          index++;
          // Are we too big for the buffer? Start tossing out data
          if (index >= BUFSIZ)
              index = BUFSIZ -1;

          // Continue to read more data!
          continue;
      }

      // Got a \n or \r new line, which means the string is done.
      clientline[index] = 0;

      // Print it out for debugging.
      Serial.println(clientline);
  ...
```

I do read in the Ethernet library itself there are both

```
virtual int read();
```

and

```
virtual int read(uint8_t *buf, size_t size);
```

member functions available. However, all the examples of the pointer string, are only showing cases of [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol), not [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol). I suspect this may have to do with the statelessness of UDP.

Where the practicality of not knowing what is in the client buffer and what its length is as to read it, may be the preventative reason I don't see any examples of it being used on TCP. Where it may be simple enough to try out.

Actually, the `client.available()` returns the received size, so it should be possible to:

```
...
int _available = client.available();
if (_available> 0) {
  client.read(clientline, _available);
...
```

Note both create a string of chars. Not to confused with the [String](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject) class.